# How to obtain videos from m3u8 links

Tags: video, video-streaming, vlc, m3u8

Ive been trying to make videos stream directly into my VLC, but very few videos actually work. For exemple, take this m3u8 link: https://e4.habrox.xyz/ingest01/66616.m3u8?sf=RUFjU2EwWjBwQQ==&token=IkENT0ZMVMeZtmUsx_Oing&expires=1606628782&rnd=

I want to understand why this works in the normal webpage where I took it, but it doesnt work when I try to use VLC.

[Image showing the link is valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzvEF.png)

[image showing it wont play in VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRz8z.png)

Comment: What is _"the normal webpage where I took it,"_? Your m3u8 link has expired so no-one can test anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a key or specific IP that you need in order to access the video. When I try and access the link, it returns `403 Forbidden` which would likely mean that VLC is running into the same error.

As for a way to fix this, you would probably want to make sure that whatever identifier is being sent with the get request is somehow provided. As for downloading it, I would recommend using something like `youtube-dl` and then run it in VLC. Unfortunately, I cannot access the link so I cannot say whether or not `youtube-dl` works.